vue3: how to access variables in <script setup> from export default
When I make a project migration from vue2 to vue3, in the vue3 script setup segment, there is a variable, but I need to access it in the method in export default part which is from vue2 project. If I access it directly, it will throw an error which means 'undefined' or 'not defined'.
<template>
  <button @click="btnClick">{{layout}}</button>           //{{layout}} works fine
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const layout = ref("someting")
  defineOptions({
    name: 'App'
  });
</script>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'MyApp',
    methods: {
      btnClick: function(e){
        console.log(layout)             //an error will be thrown
      }
    }
  }
</script>

The error detail informaiton is below:
Uncaught ReferenceError: layout is not defined
    btnClick App.vue:19
    0 App.vue:2
    callWithErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:195
    callWithAsyncErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:202
    invoker runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:693
    addEventListener runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:644
    patchEvent runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:662
    patchProp runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:739
    mountElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4641


If you want to use vue2 and vue3 together,you should only create one script,and move the content of script setup to setup function.


<template>
  <button @click="btnClick">{{layout}}</button>           
</template>
<script>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  export default {
    setup() {
      const layout = ref("someting")
      return {
        layout
      }
    },
    name: 'MyApp',
    methods: {
      btnClick: function(e) {
        console.log(this.layout)
      }
    }
  }
</script>




It works, the 
If you want to access it in the method in export default part, declare variable in the setup().
<template>
  <button @click="btnClick">{{ layout }}</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'MyApp',
  setup() {
    const layout = ref('something');

    const btnClick = () => {
      console.log(layout.value);
    };

    // return variables and methods to make them available on the component instance
    return {
      layout,
      btnClick
    };
  }
};
</script>


vue3 Composition API: setup() Document https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html

hi, I have too many methods such as click event within too many components file from vue2 project, If I should remove methods segment, and move them into setup()? It will cause us huge work.  It seemed that I can't keep btn click event still in the method part if I want to access 'layout' variable. Thanks

If it is difficult for you to remove function from the methods part, you can place the variable inside the data(){} and access it in the method using this.
<script> export default {   name: 'MyApp',   data() {     return {       layout: 'something'     };   },   methods: {     btnClick: function (e) {       console.log(this.layout);     }   } }; </script>

if you want to migrate from vue2 to vue3, you can write it in script setup
<template>
  <button @click="btnClick">{{layout}}</button>          
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const layout = ref("someting")
  function btnClick(){
    console.log(layout.value);
  }
</script>

